# How to check values is existed on table using SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Table

```
RawID data
1     A
2     B
3     C 
4     D
```

I have value RawID list (2,4,5). I want to know (2,4,5) is existed or not.
i have tried below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE rawid IN (2,4,5)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

But 2, 4 is existed on table, it returned '1'. 
But i want to get '0' because (2,4,5) all value is not existed on table.

```
if (1,2,3),  return 1
if (2,3), return 1,
if (1,3,4) return 1
if (1,5) return 0
if (2,6) return 0
```

Could you give to me idea to check that all data is existed on table or not using SQL Query??

Answer (score 1):

check for number no rows that matches the input. Example for rawid 2, 4, 5 there should be 3 rows

```
select  case    when    (select count(*) from table where rawid in (2, 4, 5)) = 3
        then    1
        else    0
        end

select  case    when    (select count(*) from table where rawid in (2, 3)) = 2
        then    1
        else    0
        end
```

Comment: This is assuming that `rawid` is unique (a fair assumption based on the column name) - for non-unique columns you better use `count(distinct columnName)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want flexibility, you can do:

```
with vals as (
      select *
      from (values (2, 4, 5)) v(val)
     )
select (case when count(*) = max(c.cnt) then 1 else 0 end)
from t join
     vals
     on t.rawid = v.val cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from vals) c;
```

This looks a little  more complicated than other solutions, but you only have to change the `values()` line in the query for it to work on any number of values.

(This assumes that `rowid` has no duplicates.)